# Implementing a very simple memory block for quick allocation and memory alignment. C++

Tags: c++, c++17

This is programmed in Visual Studio 2019 with the C++17 feature set.

The intent with this code is to be able to create memory blocks of the specified alignment and size, so as to have contiguous cache-friendly memory and to only do one malloc and free for the whole block. Is there something wrong or missing from this implementation so that it would effectively fulfill its purpose?

#### MemoryBlock.h

```
#pragma once
class MemoryBlock
{
private:
    void* p_rawMem;
    void* p_currentMemLocation;
    size_t p_currentMemLocationOffset;
    size_t p_totalMemSize;
    size_t p_remainingMemSize;
    size_t p_alignment;
    void *p_lastMemByteLocation;
    void p_addCurrentMemLocation(size_t delta);
public:
    MemoryBlock(size_t size, size_t alignment);
    void* getMemoryWith(size_t size, size_t alignemnt);
    ~MemoryBlock();
};
```

#### MemoryBlock.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
#include "MemoryBlock.h"

void MemoryBlock::p_addCurrentMemLocation(size_t delta)
{
    if (delta == 0) {
        return;
    }
    p_currentMemLocationOffset += delta;
    assert((p_currentMemLocationOffset) <= p_totalMemSize);
    p_remainingMemSize -= delta;
    if (p_remainingMemSize == 0) {
        p_currentMemLocation = p_lastMemByteLocation;
    }
    else {
        p_currentMemLocation = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(p_currentMemLocation) + delta);
    }

}

MemoryBlock::MemoryBlock(size_t size, size_t alignment):
    p_rawMem(_aligned_malloc(size, alignment)),
    p_currentMemLocation(p_rawMem),
    p_currentMemLocationOffset(0),
    p_totalMemSize(size),
    p_remainingMemSize(size),
    p_alignment(alignment),
    p_lastMemByteLocation(static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(p_rawMem) + (size - 1)))
{
}

void* MemoryBlock::getMemoryWith(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
    if (size > p_totalMemSize) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("size must be greater than 0");
    }
    if (alignment == 0 || (alignment &(alignment-1))!= 0) {//checks it alignment is power of 2
        throw std::invalid_argument("alignment should be a power of 2.");
    }
    if (alignment > p_alignment) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("alignment requirement is greater than the memory block alignment.");
    }
    if (size > p_remainingMemSize) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (p_totalMemSize == p_remainingMemSize) {
        p_addCurrentMemLocation(size);
        return p_rawMem;
    }
    p_addCurrentMemLocation((std::ceil(p_currentMemLocationOffset/(double)alignment)*alignment)-p_currentMemLocationOffset);
    void* retVal = p_currentMemLocation;
    p_addCurrentMemLocation(size);
    return retVal;
}

MemoryBlock::~MemoryBlock()
{
    _aligned_free(p_rawMem);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    MemoryBlock memBlock(1024,1024);
    int *memBlockIntPtr = new(memBlock.getMemoryWith(sizeof(int),alignof(int))) int(1);
    std::cout << *memBlockIntPtr << std::endl;
    constexpr size_t intArrSize = 4;
    int *memBlockIntArrPtr = static_cast<int*>(memBlock.getMemoryWith(sizeof(int)*intArrSize, alignof(int)));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < intArrSize; i++)
    {
        new (&memBlockIntArrPtr[i]) int(i);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < intArrSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << memBlockIntArrPtr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also ask you if the usage of the code is correct in the main function, and if I'm handling the void pointers adequately in both single-variable and array cases. If not, of course, please correct me with an explanation. Say if I'm doing main, specifically, correctly or the whole thing- and if not, make it clear why. Also suggest if I should be using an underlying memory buffer of char* instead of void* (perhaps combined with static arrays).

Comment: What do you mean by *"I'm doing main"*?

Comment: "error: use of undeclared identifier 'p_lastMemByteLocation'" I cannot compile your code. I think you forgot to add the member. Can you check that?

Comment: @henje done. Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use C++17 aligned `new` or `aligned_malloc()`

`_aligned_malloc()` is a Windows-specific, non-portable function. Luckily, C++17 added the portable `aligned_malloc()` without an underscore. It also introduces a variant of `new` that allows aligned allocation. The latter would look like so:

```
#include <new>
...
MemoryBlock::MemoryBlock(size_t size, size_t alignment):
    p_rawMem((void *)new(std::align_val_t(alignemnt)) char[size]),
    ...
{
}
```

## Unnecessary special case for `p_remainingMemSize == 0`

Why is this a special case in `p_addCurrentMemLocation`? Just adding `delta` to the current pointer is perfectly fine. A pointer that points just beyond the end of an array or an allocated memory region is still a valid pointer.

## Consider avoiding the check for `delta == 0`

An `if`-statement is not free, especially not if the branch predictor cannot correctly predict the result of the condition. If `delta` is zero, then the rest of the code still works correctly, and it's just two additions and a subtraction.

## Don't use floating point math

You should not need to use floating point math to calculate how much to advance `p_currentMemLocationOffset` inside `getMemoryWith()`. Depending on which processor your code is running on, converting to `double` and back to `size_t` can be an expensive operation. Furthermore, `double` has less precision than `size_t` on 64-bits machines, so the result might be wrong if very large memory blocks are used.

Instead of `ceil(p_CurrentMemLocationOffset / (double)alignment)`, use the fact that integer division rounds down, and compensate for this by adding `alignment - 1` first:

```
p_addCurrentMemLocation((((p_currentMemLocationOffset + alignment - 1) / alignment) * alignment) - p_currentMemLocationOffset);
```

Alternatively, use the modulo operation to determine how much to add:

```
p_addCurrentMemLocation((alignment - p_currentMemLocationOffset % alignment) % alignment);
```

The latter will be especially fast if the compiler can deduce that `alignment` is always a power of two.

## `char *` vs. `void *`

It's probably easier to use `char *` internally for the pointers, since you are doing arithmetic on them. And if you do that, the only time you need to cast is when returning from `getMemoryWith()`.

Comment: Very useful analysis!!! I must point out however a few things: visual studio does not provide an implementation for c++17`s aligned_alloc(), crazy right? and also, I use assert() because if everything goes right in the public function then that private function should *never* have that assertion fail, if it does it is I who has done a mistake not the public interface caller.

Comment: also, are you sure the syntax you show for the aligned overload of the c++17 new operator is correct? gives me a compile error.(again I dont know if this is just visual studio deviating from the standard again or an error on your part, please confirm.)

Comment: Ok, that's a good reason for having both `assert()` and `throw()`. Keep on doing that then :) I did make a mistake in the example of aligned `new`. Also, for the aligned `new` operator, you might have to `#include <new>`. But it might be that MSVC does not support aligned `new` anyway.